# Why does an "external member" of a thesis defense committee come to your defense?

Tags: phd, defense, thesis-committee, turkey

I am curious why would some professor from another university come to my university (in Turkey) merely for my defense.

What benefit does this professor have in it?

Do universities pay professors for being an "external member" of any student's thesis defense?

Comment: My external member just used Skype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some external professors are in the same field and others are not. They serve different purposes. They might be paid a small stipend, but it is usually (as far as I know) just an honorarium. The receiving institution probably also pays for travel and lodging if the person is from away.

For the professor it is just a part of service to the profession. Their own institution may provide some recognition for it or not. Often annual evaluations are on research, teaching, and service.

However, the purpose of an in-field visitor is, at least partly, to give some external validation to the program that is visited. I've been asked if I think the entire program is up to the standards I would expect. This help prevent academic incest where a department only speaks among its own members and loses connection to the larger goals. "Would you give a doctorate to this candidate based on the thesis and overall program?" Here the visitor is from a different university for this to make sense. Sometimes from a different country.

The purpose of an external member of an examination committee, however, is quite different and may even come from the same university. In mathematics, the visitor might come from philosophy or a language department. They are normally not expected to read the dissertation and couldn't be expected to understand it. But they are expected to ask a question or two of the candidate and the quality of the answer can be heavily weighted in the evaluation of the student. Sometimes it is just a request to explain to the visitor some terminology used in the defense talk. A layperson's explanation is expected, and the candidate normally is expected to do a good job with the answer. Advanced students who can't intelligently discuss elementary things in their field are at a handicap. I've heard of situations in which the examination was failed for this reason alone.

Comment: I've also served as an "External Examiner" for students at other universities (in the Netherlands, Canada, and New Zealand)  In those cases I was paid an honorarium and travel expenses in exchange not just for attending the defense but also for conducting a very thorough written review of the dissertation similar to the kind of peer review that would be done for journal publication for each of the chapters of the dissertation.  This kind of "External Examiner" arrangement is not common in the US in my experience.

Comment: My experience is similar to Brian's (France, Denmark, Israel, and the Netherlands).  I've also been an external member of a few US thesis committees, and (by department policy) all my PhD students have had one thesis committee member from another university, but none of these required a thorough, formal written review of the thesis.

Answer (score 1):

In my department at least, external committee members are rarely there ***just*** for the defense. We usually take advantage of their presence to have them give a talk as a guest speaker. And as such, they're paid and given accommodations as guest speakers, even though their main purpose of travel would be to take part in the defense. In this sense, the professor gets the advantage of having been invited to speak at an external institution (great line on your CV) and potentially meet new and future colleagues in the field, and the institution gets the advantage of having this guest visit and disseminate their research. It's all a part of networking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the system is in Turkey, but I can comment on the system in the UK. Here the external examiner of a PhD thesis is the primary examiner (they ask the hardest questions, and it is their judgement that weighs most heavily in the evaluation of the work), and they are expected to be an expert in the field that is the subject of the thesis.

Why do they do this? As others have said, they might enjoy the visit to another university, or another country. They might like the opportunity to give a talk at another institution, although from what I've seen in the UK that only happens some of the time. Of course, they might just be interested in the research itself! Primarily, however, I think this is something that people do for two reasons (depending on how one looks at it, there might only be one reason, as they bleed into one another somewhat).

1. **Duty.** Being the external examiner for a PhD is like being a referee for a journal. It doesn't pay (or at least not well—they might just cover your costs), but it's an important part of maintaining academic standards in one's field.
2. **As part of a system of exchange.** If I were to act as an external examiner for a PhD thesis, then the supervisor of that student (or perhaps the internal examiner, or the department more broadly) owes me a favour, that I might call in at a later date by asking them to examine one of my students. Alternatively, I might do it in the expectation that *someone* (preferably someone who is both good and influential in the field) will act as the external examiner for one of my students in the future, or to "pay it forward" because someone has done it for me in the past. In other words: this is one of those duties for which one doesn't necessarily expect to be compensated immediately, or even by those who one is doing the favour for. Rather, it's one of the things that makes the academic world go round, just like refereeing papers, assessing grant applications, or writing tenure letters.